# What does 'choo mean in " 'Choo fall over for"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> "Fell over," said Harry.

" **'Choo** fall over for?" sniggered Stan.

What does **'Choo** mean?  I suppose it's a dialectal spelling of some word, but I can't figure it out.

-- From Harry Potter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the word "choo" is short for **what you**, with the auxiliary verb omitted. This line by Stan is basically:

> "What (did) you fall over for?"

Dropping the auxiliary "did", **what did you** becomes **what you**, then **whachyou**, then **choo**. Stan is asking, "*What did you do that for?*" "*Why did you fall over?*" That is why Harry responds by saying, "*I didn't do it on purpose.*"

I found a page with your quoted text. If you go down a bit further in the text, you will see another instance of this grammatical phenomenon.

> "Choo lookin' at?" said Stan.

And this line means "*What are you looking at?*" with the auxiliary "are" dropped.

Also worth noting that two more common contractions for "what are/do you" are **watcha** or **whatcha**.

Comment: Yeah, I did see ""Choo lookin' at?" said Stan." Thanks! Is it a kind of some British dialect?

Comment: Also there is another line "Take 'er away, Ern, " said Stan...  I suppose it's "Take her away", but I don't know who "her" refers to. There is not a girl or women in the context. Can you also do me a favor to explain it as well? Thanks!

Comment: @dan I am not a BrE speaker, so I can't give you a definitive answer. My hunch is that this contraction is the author's attempt at transcribing a speech style characteristic of certain region/personal choice/social class. Some people probably speak this way, but this contraction doesn't appear to be prevalent.

Comment: @dan Okay, sure... I have never read Harry Potter, but I managed to find a page with the text you are asking about. The story introduces a bus driver and his bus prior to the line in question. It seems to me *her* refers to the bus or magical vessel that the driver Ernie drives. "Take her away" means *Take off, Ern!* When we ask someone to start something, like a performance or a speech, we also say "Take it away!"